# Where are images saved inside a remote docker registry?

Tags: docker, manifest, docker-registry

After tagging and pushing an image to a remote registry, I want to:

- delete it
- push the same image again.

So, I delete an image from a remote docker registry and delete the `.../registry/v2/repository/...` directory too which contains the image files (in order to clean the registry catalogue). I then delete the blobs using the garbage collector. All is good to this point.

But when I try to push the same image again to the registry, I get the following output:

[image]

When I check the registry files, I find that the layers aren't pushed (only the manifest revisions and tags details).

I wonder where the images files are saved inside the registry knowing that the layers shown in the picture above are nowhere to be found in the registry machine (no files and no directories with such names or numbers).

I am just trying to clean the docker registry and be able to completely clear any unused layers, blobs, manifests, images, digest, etc .. clean all that belong to a specific image.

Comment: I would suggest running `docker system prune` (perhaps with `--filter` switch not to prune all the images) on the registry machine. This should effectively drop all the cached docker image layers (not used by other images having active containers). On the next push all layers should upload.

Comment: @helvete : Thanks for the reply, but there is no such command for the docker registry in the HTTP API v2 that correspond to `docker system prune` . And I cannot run this command from within the docker registry since docker isn't a command inside it.

Comment: Well, maybe it is impossible to achieve what you intend using the API...

Comment: @helvete : I know it is doable because it is not something fancy. All I want to do is to just remove manually all the files associated with an image from inside the docker registry. Nothing difficult with that, right ?. But I want to know where these files are inside the docker-registry. (P.S.: I really hope that you voted to close the question based on what you know not what you think is possible)

Comment: So you are trying to do it using the API and also saying there is no way to do this using the API. It is understandable as this action is IMHO not really meant for the clients to  consider. Docker registry aside, the image is surely cached by docker itself, so the `prune` would help. It is of course possible to do this manually, by deleting the layers. I don't see why would you want to do that, but try running `docker inspect {image-name-or-id}`, it prints where the image metadata are placed within given file system. You can go from there..
P.S. I haven't voted to close the question at all.

Comment: @helvete : In a nutshell, I pushed an image successfully. Then I deleted its layers and manifest using the API. I also deleted layers associated blobs using `garbage collection`. But the `local docker` says a `layer exists` when pushing the same image again to the `registry`. Looking inside the `registry` itself, nothing is there. That is why I am asking where exactly the image files are stored inside the `registry`. (Btw, I've never said I want to use the API. I just said the prune command cannot be run from the API. Also, docker commands cannot be run from the registry)